# waiting for future function to finish before proceeding in flutter

Tags: flutter

i have a future function in flutter. I want the future function to finish executing before flutter can move to the next line of code. I am using future.wait but it looks like it is not working for me. i also try to create independent function and add async and await and then call that function in the constructor but it is not working either.

here is my code

this is a singleton class to keep an object that will be access through many classes.
in the constructor i am using future.wait to wait for the function to finish .

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import '../repositories/objectbox_store.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ObjectService {
  late ObjectBox objectBox;
  static final ObjectService _instance = ObjectService._internal();

  // passes the instantiation to the _instance object
  factory ObjectService() => _instance;

  //initialize variables in here
    ObjectService._internal()  {
     
    Future.wait([
        initializeObject()
      ]);
    
  }

  //short getter for my variable
  ObjectBox get myVariable => objectBox;



  Future<void> initializeObject () async {
    // This is required so ObjectBox can get the application directory
    // to store the database in.
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    objectBox = await ObjectBox.create();
  }
}
```

here is my calling class

```
class ViewTransaction extends StatefulWidget {
  ViewTransaction({
    Key? key,
    required this.isSearch,
    required this.transactionType
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool isSearch;
  final String transactionType;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ViewTransactionState();
  }
}

class ViewTransactionState extends State<ViewTransaction> {
  int count = 0;
  //ViewTransactionSummaryBloc get bloc => Provider.of<ViewTransactionSummaryBloc>(context);
  late Stream<List<Income>> _stream;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: colorPrimary,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AddEditIncomeForm( addEditIndicator: 'Add')));
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
          ),
        ),
        body:  incomeSummaryStream()
    );
  }

  Widget incomeSummaryStream()  {
    ObjectService _myService =  ObjectService();

   Stream<List<Income>> _stream =  _myService.myVariable.store
        .box<Income>()
        .query()
        .watch(triggerImmediately: true)
        .map((query) => query.find());
}
```

i am calling    ObjectService _myService =  ObjectService() in ViewTransaction  class.
i am expecting the future in ObjectService to finish before moving to the next line which is

```
Stream<List<Income>> _stream =  _myService.myVariable.store
```

when i try to access _myService.myVariable.store, i get the following error

[image]

please help. am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't use `Future` in constructors. Constructors must always be synchronous.

Alternatively, you can make a special method that would initialize your object and call it before the first use.
Example:

```
class ObjectService {
  static final ObjectService instance = ObjectService._();

  late final ObjectBox _objectBox;

  ObjectService._();

  ObjectBox get objectBox => _objectBox;

  Future<void> init() async {
    _objectBox = await ObjectBox.create();
  }
}
```

And in your `main` function (the `main` function needs to be made asynchronous):

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Waiting for [ObjectService] to be initialized
  await ObjectService.instance.init();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```